# SWTableViewCell - No animation, but delegate methods are being called

Tags: uitableview, ios7, swipe, swipe-gesture

I have spent countless hours trying to get [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) working, and I've run out of ideas. I'm trying to integrate it into a `UITableViewController` that contains a custom `UITableViewCell` (subclassed). For some reason, I can't get any of the animation working. I thought at first that [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) might have been causing the problem, but after completely removing it's usage, the swipe still doesn't produce animation. So that's not the culprit.

I've gone so far as to try a different cell swipe implementation ([TLSwipeForOptionsCell](https://github.com/TeehanLax/UITableViewCell-Swipe-for-Options)), but I get the same results of no action. I've also tried [MCSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell), which *does* work in showing the swipe action, but unfortunately presents it's own problems since it doesn't support auto-layout.

For the `SWTableViewCell`, I can confirm by stepping through the code that

1. The class receives the gesture and steps through the logic of the code appropriately.
2. The delegate methods are getting fired appropriately, so the control should have done what it was supposed to do.

However, nothing happens in my table view cell. No animation, no glitch/flicker, no sign that anything has changed.

I've also followed the guidance for using [table view editing](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell/issues/167), which did remove the default "delete" option (desired to remove that anyway), but it still doesn't work.

As you can see in the documentation on GitHub, integrating this should be super simple, but it just doesn't work for me.

Target is iOS 7.1 SDK.

For `SWTableViewCell` (the swipe implementation I'd prefer to use), I've just noticed that the selection of the cell is lost almost immediately when starting to drag. If I touch and hold on the cell, it is selected. I move just slightly, and selection is lost. However, with  MCSwipeTableViewCell the selection is **not** lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the expense of looking like an idiot, I'm going to log what the problem was just in case someone else makes the same mistake.

In addition to the symptoms above, I was also having a problem where touching on the cell so that the selection state was triggered would result in a highlight that covered all of my controls--the cell looked empty/blank. That was also resolved with the solution below.

In Interface Builder, I had set the `backgroundView` Outlet to `contentView`. Don't do that. Bad stuff happens.

Hope someone else ends up benefiting from this.